# Android create custom button with one rounded corner

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

[image]

I would like to implement the black button from this image taken from material.io which is used to expand the bottom sheet. The content of the button is not important its  achieving the one rounded corner. When trying to set the corner radius I only have the ability to round all 4 corners not one individual corner. Could someone please advise how they did this? They dont provide any example of this button on that website.

I have this so far which does not work:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBottomSheetGratitude"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Examples"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bottom_sheet"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_drop_up_24"
            app:iconPadding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:topLeftRadius="1000dp" />
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/one_rounded"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24px"
        app:iconPadding="4dp"
      />
```

with:

```
<style name="one_rounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">0dp</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">50%</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Using Material Button:

Define a style in your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="shapeAppearance">@style/MyShapeAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyShapeAppearance">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyTopRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomRight">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerFamilyBottomLeft">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">10dp</item>
</style>
```

And then use this style in your MaterialButton. For more info, see the [docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons) or an [usage example](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#usage).

### Normal Button:

You can use a [ShapeDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape) as a background for the button, for example:

`bg_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ff000000"/>

    <corners android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in your layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/cornerButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
    ... />
```

Comment: I updated my question with the code I tried, it doesnt work, the button stays red which im guessing has something to do with the default theme. The corners  dont change at all

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you tried,  but Try it like this:

> android:topLeftRadius="10dp"

Answer (score 0):

The `android:background` attribute will not work with **MaterialButton** as it uses it internally. I think they have made it possible to change it in the newest alpha version of the library but not in the stable versions, yet. So here is how you are going to do it.

First, make sure that your app theme is inheriting from the Material Theme so that we can use all of the material attributes (you can use any of the material themes).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
...
</style>
```

Now, define a style for the **ShapeAppearance** of the **MaterialButton**.

```
<style name="shapeAppearance">
    <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Finally, use it in your XML code where you are defining the button.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
            app:shapeAppearance="@style/shapeAppearance"
            android:text="@string/main_fragment_login_label"/>
```

Now your button should look like below, which is exactly what you are looking for.

[image]